# Ignore unresolved symbols when compiling java with javac

Tags: java, javac

I am using Google Plugin in STS and [it reports missing class](https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues/70). I decided to go a quick and dirty way and download the class, compile it and put it into plugin folder or jar file.

The class is here: [Java2HTMLEntityReader.java](https://github.com/lsegal/jml4disco/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.core/formatter/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter/comment/Java2HTMLEntityReader.java)

When I compile, I of course get some errors:

```
Java2HTMLEntityReader.java:19: error: package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser does not exist
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.*;
^
Java2HTMLEntityReader.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
public class Java2HTMLEntityReader extends SubstitutionTextReader {
                                           ^
  symbol: class SubstitutionTextReader
Java2HTMLEntityReader.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
                setSkipWhitespace(false);
                ^
  symbol:   method setSkipWhitespace(boolean)
  location: class Java2HTMLEntityReader
Java2HTMLEntityReader.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
                        c = nextChar();
                            ^
  symbol:   method nextChar()
  location: class Java2HTMLEntityReader
Java2HTMLEntityReader.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
                } else if (!ScannerHelper.isWhitespace((char) c)) {
                            ^
  symbol:   variable ScannerHelper
  location: class Java2HTMLEntityReader
Note: Java2HTMLEntityReader.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
5 errors
```

That's because I didn't give the java compiler refference to the package. And I don't intend to! I want to compile it with those errors, I assume it will work when I put it on the correct classpath.

Comment: Include jar with org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser to classpath of javac or you can take only SubstitutionTextReader.class

Comment: How should the compiler be able to compile if he has no idea about the involved types?

Comment: @LutzHorn What does it need those types for? Java isn't memory aware, there's no static allocation so no need what data are we talking about. After all, all ArrayLists are just `List<Object>` and the actual `<Something>` is not important at compile time. Do not mistake Java for other languages that actually do something during compilation.

Comment: Maybe. But the errors you get are not about `List<Object>`. They are about methods like `setSkipWhitespace`. Where do they come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd use the Eclipse compiler to compile that class, you could request creation of `.class` files despite compile errors. On the command line this is done using the option `-proceedOnError`. To the best of my knowledge javac does not have such an option.

Mind you, that unresolved types in API positions (super types, method signatures) may render the resulting class file useless.

I don't really see a good reason for hacking such a stub .class file for compilation. If you have the corresponding jar file available at runtime, you should really use the same jar also during compilation.

Comment: I tried once I found out, to no avail though. `javac` ignored provided jar classpath and kept complaining about missing classes, though I was able to locate those in the jar archive. I have eclipse though so I'll try maybe it will work.

Comment: @TomášZato, `javac` ignoring jars on the classpath sounds like a bug in your configuration / invocation of javac.

Answer (score -5):

Successful compilation means there should be no errors in the source code.

If your code contains compilation errors it cannot compile and will not produce a `.class` file

Comment: Not true. You can have `.class` files with unresolved references just fine. Do not forget java compilation process is symmetric.

Comment: If you compile a single class, all its references should exist on the class path.
On the other hand, you can use complex referencing mechanism like `maven` where you can give maven scope `provided`.

Comment: The references are not necessary to create the bytecode. Whether they are there or not has no influence on the bytecode produced. It might be so that javac doesn't allow you to compile - but it's certainly possible, just as it's possible to decompile class without those refferences.

Comment: That is what I mean, javac finishes with errors and so will not produce a `.calss` file